# Funky mail sorting and grouping in Outlook 2007

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, sorting

In outlook 2007

I group mails in a folder by **subject** with mails in each subject group sorted by **Received** date (newest to oldest)

This works fine; I tick 'Subject' and 'Show in groups' in the context menu of the folder's table header. Life is good.

But the subject groups in the mail folder are sorted alphabetically. I would like the group which has the newest mail to be the first group. Similar to how the arrange by 'Conversation' works

Can this be done?

I'm not averse to an add-in/macro type solution if anyone can point me at examples of implementing custom sorting in Outlook

Answer (score 2):

Add "Conversation" (there is field called that) column to the columns by using "Customize Current View" and the "Fields" button. Then group by this column by dragging it.

Did you mean that result?

Comment: afraid not, the group by conversation is close. Outlook puts the conversation in a tree so sometimes the newest mail in that conversation isn't at the top. I'm generally interested in the newest mail from each current subject (conversation)

Comment: do this and then "order by received"... that should do. 
Or I do not understand exact result wanted...  :)

Comment: Not understanding i think :)  I am after grouping by subject and being able to control how the goups are sorted in the folder (not how the mails in each group are sorted)

Comment: Excuse me, but I am using this and now my mails are grouped by conversation (subject) and conversation groups are sorted from the latest conversation to the oldest... and also when I want I order them by received so I end up mails in each group sorted by date also...

Comment: Ooops! You want "subject grouping" behaving like "Conversation grouping"... But why? Conversation field is ther for this.

Comment: often people dont reply to the most recent mail in a conversation. So even though theirs is the most recent mail, outlook puts it as a leaf under the mail they replied to. So I end up with this mail being 'buried' in the conversation. So outlooks conv. view is actually too good for me